# Treat file as memory block in C

Tags: c, file, memory

Is there any way to make pointers read a file as a block of memory in C? 
Can access of a file can be faster...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Treating a file as memory (and letting the OS do the file IO for you) is termed '[memory mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file)'.

On POSIX (e.g. ***Linux***), the [`mmap()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html) function does this.

On ***Windows***, the [`OpenFileMapping()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366791%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and friends do this.  Microsoft have excellent description of how this works, why to use it, and particulars on their platform [*here*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366791%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Do you have a C example to manage a matrix, instead of reading file, manage memory block?

Comment: A very huge one, lets say 10,000x100,000 or something like that, can it be spplitted so in C I can manipulate it?

Comment: You use the BLAS library.  There is no better way.

Comment: BLAS? Why is the only feasible way, so BLAS can do...memory handling with big matices?

Comment: if your matrix doesn't fit in memory, you'ld have to read it in and manipulate it block by block.  Or use a computer with more memory.